# Ascii error when trying to write in file open with codecs lib

Tags: python, utf-8, ascii

Code

```
# -*- coding: ISO-8859-15 -*-
import sys
import codecs
filename2 = "log_unicode2.log"
log_file2 = codecs.open(filename2, "w", "utf-8")
sys.stdout = log_file2
log_file2.write('aééé')
```

Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "snippet_problem_unicode.py", line 7, in <module>
    log_file2.write('a├®├®├®')
  File "C:\Users\dev1\Envs\atao\lib\codecs.py", line 691, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\dev1\Envs\atao\lib\codecs.py", line 351, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xc3 in position 1: ordinal
not in range(128)
```

Contexte

- Windows 7
- Python 2.6
- Eclipse

'aééé' is a byte string (latin-1) which need to be converted to utf-8.
Why do this conversion involve ascii codec ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are writing a **byte string** to a file object expecting a **`unicode` value**. To go from byte string to unicode value Python has to decode the bytestring. This decoding uses the default ASCII codec.

Either:

1. Use a unicode literal instead of a byte string:

   ```
   log_file2.write(u'aééé')
   ```
2. Explicitly decode the bytestring to Unicode first, using your source file encoding:

   ```
   log_file2.write('aééé'.decode('latin1'))
   ```
3. Not use `codecs.open()` but open the file using the built-in `open()` function instead, then manually decode, then encode to UTF:

   ```
   log_file2 = open(filename2, "w")
   log_file2 .write('aééé'.decode('latin1').encode('utf8')
   ```

   or use a `unicode` literal and encode manually:

   ```
   log_file2 = open(filename2, "w")
   log_file2 .write(u'aééé'.encode('utf8'))
   ```

Comment: Said diffrently : a byte string is implicitely the result of a former ascii encoding and is decoded as such by the codecs lib.

Comment: @LBarret: a byte string *may* contain textual information. When attempting to use it as Unicode text it'll be decoded with the assumption it is using the ASCII codec.